# Django NoReverseMatch at /services/ 'services' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display a group of images classified by category. When the user clicks on a category name, the page should display the images that belongs to that category. I'm getting the the next browser error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /services/
'services' is not a registered namespace

. . .

Error during template rendering
```

The models belongs to different apps, one (that contains the Category model) works fine, and this other (That contains the Services model) just works if I delete the html content that I need. Help me please.

Here are my files:

**home_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='category_home')
    description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=500, default="Service")
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('services:services_by_category', args=[self.slug])
```

**services_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from home_app.models import Category

class Services(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    completed=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='services_services')
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Service'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Services'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s de %s' % (self.category, self.title)
```

**services_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Services
from home_app.models import Category

def service_list(request,category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    services = Services.objects.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_slug)
        services = services.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'services_app/services.html', {'categories':categories, 'category':category, 'services':services,})
```

**services_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from services_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.service_list, name='Services'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>', views.service_list, name='services_by_category'),
]
```

**services_app/templates/services_app/services.html**

```
    {% extends "home_app/base.html" %}   
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    
    <!-- The app only works if I delete this section -->
    
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul>
            {% for c in categories %}
                <li>
               <h4><a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a></h4>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% endif %}</h1>
        {% for service in services %}
            <img src="{{service.image.url}}">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also my main urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home_app.urls')),
    path('services/', include('services_app.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contact_app.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change en `models.py` the following:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('services_by_category', args=[self.slug])
```

'cause you have not defined the `namespace` services.